# amazon ec2 detection from CentOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

I have list of VMs on which my application is installed. I want to know on which VM the application is installed. Is there a way to find out the host VM environment?

Is there a way I can detect from within my program that I am running on a Amazon EC2 hosted virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` with a reasonable timeout and if you get something back, you're running on Amazon.

You can read about this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html).

Here's what you get when you're running in EC2.

```
% curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
iam/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
kernel-id
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

...and from a regular machine:

```
# curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ --connect-timeout 3
curl: (28) connect() timed out!
```